# When the magnetic poles of the Sun flip (once in 11 years), is the Earth hit by more galactic cosmic rays?

Tags: interplanetary, the-sun, magnetic-field, cosmic-radiation

The Sun protects us from cosmic rays from beyond the solar system. Every 11 years, the Sun's poles reverse.

Solar cosmic rays are greatest during the reversal.

During the reversal, are we hit by more galactic cosmic rays too?  Does the reversal reduce the Sun's protection from them?

Would that harm astronauts heading for Mars at such a time?

Comment: Relevance to space exploration?

Comment: @OrganicMarble The cosmic rays are relevant. They could disturb or even destroy electronics, for example.

Comment: @Infrisios the *question* needs to show relevance to space exploration to be on topic.  Not a comment.

Comment: @Infrisios Thankx for the comment. I edited.

Comment: The Forbush decrease phenomena is linked to coronal mass ejections, which are more common at solar max, not the reversal direction of the solar magnetic field itself.

Answer (score 3):

1, Yes, but in an opposite sense.
Cosmic rays are densest when the solar cycle is least active,
but that corresponds to when there are the fewest sunspots.
But the magnetic field reverses when there are the most sunspots, at "solar max."

2, Yes.
NASA has published extensively about the [risks](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/goddard/2019/how-nasa-protects-astronauts-from-space-radiation-at-moon-mars-solar-cosmic-rays) of cosmic rays to astronauts outside Earth's magnetosphere.